# Turning multiple PHP arrays into one array ready for conversion to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a multiple choice quiz game with PHP and Javascript. Questions can have 2 to 6 answers. I have been using the PHP queries in the code below to get arrays of the questions of a quiz, and the answers for each questions.

I now want to use this data in Javascript, and want to make it so each time a user clicks next question, a question and corresponding answers are displayed.

I think (but am not sure) that the best way to do this is to combine the arrays into one where the question array contains the answers arrays before converting to a javascript array.

Is this really the way I should do this, and if so how do I do so?

```
$thisquizid = $_POST['quizidvalue'];
    for ($j = 0; $j < $questionrows; ++$j)
        {
            $questionresult = pg_fetch_array($questionquery); 
            $answerquery = pg_query($db_handle, "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE questionid = '$questionresult[0]'");
            $answerrows = pg_num_rows($answerquery);  

        for ($i = 0; $i < $answerrows; ++$i)
            {
                $answerresult = pg_fetch_array($answerquery); 
            }

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this from the other direction. What should the data look like in JS? Or rather, what JSON should PHP return in order for the JS to be nice and clean. Something like:

```
var json = { // From PHP via AJAX
  "questions_and_answers": [
    {
      "question": "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
      "answers": [
        "11 meters per second",
        "24 miles an hour",
        "African or European?"
      ]
    },
    {
      "question": "If a tree falls in an empty forest does it make a sound?",
      "answers": [
        "Unequivocally, yes.",
        "Unequivocally, no.",
        "It's all subjective."
      ]
    }
  ]
};

for(var i = 0, j = json.questions_and_answers.length; i < j; i++) {
  var question = json.questions_and_answers[i].question;
  var answers = json.questions_and_answers[i].answers.join("\n");
  alert(question + "\n" + answers);
}
```

Now, what would that look like in PHP? The simplest thing to pass json_encode, since you're not using Question and Answer objects or some kind of ORM, would be nested arrays:

```
<?php
$questions_and_answers = array(
    array(
        "question" => "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
        "answers" => array(
            "11 meters per second",
            "24 miles an hour",
            "African or European?"
        )
    ),
    array(
        "question" => "If a tree falls in an empty forest does it make a sound?",
        "answers" => array(
                "Unequivocally, yes.",
                "Unequivocally, no.",
                "It's all subjective."
            )
    )
);

// Wrap in a parent object, assuming you're delivering to JS with via AJAX.
echo json_encode(array("questions_and_answers" => $questions_and_answers));
?>
```

So you're on the right track with your server-side code, but you want an empty array to populate as you loop over your database results:

```
<?php

$thisquizid = $_POST['quizidvalue'];

    $json_output = array();

    for ($j = 0; $j < $questionrows; ++$j)
        {
            $questionresult = pg_fetch_array($questionquery); 
            $answerquery = pg_query($db_handle, "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE questionid = '$questionresult[0]'");
            $answerrows = pg_num_rows($answerquery);             
            $json_output[$j] = array( "question" => $questionresult["text"], "answers" => array());

        for ($i = 0; $i < $answerrows; ++$i)
            {
                $answerresult = pg_fetch_array($answerquery);
                $json_output[$j]["answers"][] = $answerresult["text"];
            }

    }

    echo json_encode(array("questions_and_answers" => $json_output));

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to give this solution a shot first.

Comment: Good luck! Just fixed the final code block, please disregard previous hasty version. Replace the `text` in `$questionresult["text"]` and `$answerresult["text"]` with your actual column name that contains the question/answer text.

Comment: Thanks alot, I managed to get this working, your help was VERY useful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you CAN do it this way assuming you don't just want everything in Javascript (IE it is actually a quiz that people would want to cheat on so you need to store answers on your server...).

Use AJAX to call your PHP page, then just return the vales you need to display as a variable, JSON Array, whatever... Basic AJAX call will look like this:

```
var xmlhttpMain=new XMLHttpRequest();
function changeContent(){
    xmlhttpMain.open("GET", true);
    xmlhttpMain.send(null);
    xmlhttpMain.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttpMain.readyState==4 && xmlhttpMain.status==200){
            newStuff=xmlhttpMain.responseText;//This is your JSON or Array that you create in the PHP file... 
            //Then run whatever code you want here
    }
}
```

In your PHP file just use an "echo($someString);" to shoot yor info back to JS land...